# Configure solr to return no results by default

Tags: solr, lucene

Our Solr is configured to return ALL results if no valid search parameters are passed in. For example:
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?rows=1&title=bar is a valid search (title is a valid field) and it returns the proper number of results (1 out of many results). But... http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?rows=1&foo=bar returns one out of the **entire** collection (foo is not a valid field).

I read that there is a way to configure Solr to return NO results by default (instead of all). It said "adjust the requestHandler config to return all results by default" (which I assume means there is a way to return none by default) but I cannot find anything online about how to actually do this.

The reason we want this is because we're implementing a blacklist of fields that we don't want the user to search on, but by doing this, it allows all other fields through and we'd like those to return no results (or even better - an error saying the field is invalid).

Solr is being called through our API that we wrote, so even if we could add on a parameter to each call to make it return no results by default (noResultsIfNoValidSearch=true or something), that would work.

So, any ideas on how to configure Solr to return NO results by default? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Add echoParams=all into your query to see everything that the request has, coming from all configuration sources.
2. Most likely you define **q=*:*** somewhere in your configuration, that's what causing returning everything. Remove that and you should get nothing.
3. If you are using [eDixMas](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser), you can look into **uf** parameter which allows to restrict the fields users are allowed to query.

   > To allow all fields except title, use uf=*-title

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing that comes to mind is to set the [rows parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-TherowsParameter) to 0 in your API or config, depending on your requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help. I still want it to behave normally if valid terms are passed in.